# Two-column table of numbers from a geocaching site

Tags: number-property

I found this table, but can't seem to find any relation between the numbers. Also there is not much logic involved.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2002 | 13 |
| 1987 | 11 |
| 1984 | 5 |
| 1998 | 6 |
| 2004 | 22 |
| 1999 | 12 |
| ???? | ?? |

> A table with numbers. Enter the missing numbers. A lot of logic is not involved. The coordinates above are of course fictional and there is nothing to be found. [geocaching.com](https://geocaching.com)

Comment: Can you please reference the source of this table, thanks!

Comment: I recieved the table as a picture, I think it is a puzzle from geocaching. I will add all the information from the picture as it is recieved in another language.